# Super Putty Equivalent in Mac

Tags: macos, putty

Please suggest me a super putty equivalent or a tabbed putty for MAC OS X. I can use terminal for single connection but is there any application for tabbed terminal 
?

Comment: Have you tried the standard Terminal program that comes with OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `iTerm` application for tabbed terminals.

Answer (score 2):

I have found two.

Shuttle and ZOC

-winn